# Docker: Multistage builds result in one image

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I have one multi stage dockerfile:

```
# build
FROM alpine:3.18.4 AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN git clone https://github.com/app/app.git ./
RUN apk add --no-cache go
RUN go build -ldflags '-s -w'

# image
FROM alpine:3.18.4
COPY --from=build /src/app /usr/bin/
```

After that I expect to get two images but I get one image instead:

```
docker image build -t app:latest ./

docker image ls -a

REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
app       latest    001c1a4b00c8   50 minutes ago   40.8MB
```

Why I get only one image instead two images? Is it possible to get two image?

I read this: [Docker: Multistage builds result in multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234588/docker-multistage-builds-result-in-multiple-images). But author got three images by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) describes how multi-stage builds only output one image at the end. While you can integrate files from earlier stages into later stages using `COPY --from=...`, **only the final stage in the Dockerfile is used as the output image** and the intermediate stages are ignored (but may remain in the internal build cache to speed up future builds).

You can still choose to output an intermediate stage [if you specify it with `--target`](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage). For example with the Dockerfile you provided, `--target=build` will stop the build after the `build` stage completes, and the results of the `build` stage will be used as the output image.

To output several intermediate stages, you can use `docker build` several times, naming each `--target` that you're interested in. You may also wish to use `-t` to tag each stage-image with a unique name.